# Azure Function. Read Only after publishing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the portal/VS 2017 publish process?
For a long time my azure functions were running fine and then I made a trivial change to a function and republished. The whole application went 'Read Only' in the portal.

[image]

The only solution I currently have is to go into the 'App Service Editor' in the portal and remove the 'generated by' entry...
"generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.0.0"
After doing this the function app appears to be stable.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with my publish or is this just a bug in the Azure function environment? It appears to be a new issue.

Answered : No real problem.
Thanks David Ebbo, I think the issue I had was with something else in the function. I thought it was because it was 'Read Only' but looking at it now it appears to be running Ok as a 'Read Only'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. When you publish using Visual Studio, your app becomes read-only to make sure that you don't attempt to modify it via Portal editing. Instead, if you need to update your app, simply publish again via VS.

While you can override this in the settings and make it Read/Write, it is almost certainly the wrong thing to do. **99% of users should never do this!**

What's not clear from your question is why you are viewing this as a problem in the first place. The fact that the portal prevents you from editing your function does not break anything. All your functions can still run and will be triggered as expected.

Comment: Answered : No real problem. Thanks David Ebbo, I think the issue I had was with something else in the function. I thought it was because it was 'Read Only' but looking at it now it appears to be running Ok as a 'Read Only'

Comment: FYI, we'll change the message to be green instead of yellow so it doesn't make it look like something is wrong. Please mark as answered if that resolved your question.

Comment: David Ebbo, the problem is not "read only" per se.  it's that expected functionality is no longer there.  Specifically, the ability to get a clear function URL that includes the authorization code.

Comment: @Gunnar I would suggest creating a new question that focuses on this particular point

Comment: People views it as a problem cause nobody is expecting this when using the platform for the first time. Maybe a message from visual studio or the portal could fit well to instruct the user to think the right way to do the thing.